# Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate

Tags: https

I used self-signed certificate to request https buy `ASIFormDataRequest`, but But there may be a problem:

> A connection failure occurred: SSL problem (Possible causes may include a bad/expired/self-signed certificate, clock set to wrong date)

```
__block ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
[request setValidatesSecureCertificate:NO];
[request startAsynchronous];
```

This really solved my problem. But it did find other problems.

look the pictures:

[image]

[image]

I can see the HTTPS response clear-text, Is security?

Comment: but used Charles->proxy->SSL proxying Settings  can looked  cleartext